# is it safe to use "ls" in for loop in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I am using this to loop through folders in /home directory

```
for FOLDERNAME in `\ls -1 /home/`
```

i want to know is it safe

Comment: `find` may be a bit better , you could restrinct number of levels and type of entry with `-type d`

Comment: It would be better to use /bin/ls than ls.  Perhaps you could clarify your use of 'safe' for us?

Comment: It's safe enough that you won't get any diseases but other than that... who knows?

Comment: Option -1 is the default when standard output is not a terminal, so it is redundant.

Comment: The standrard reference for this is https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs but the gist is "no."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want all subdirectories in `/home`, use

```
(   # run in subshell so "shopt -s dotglob" doesn't affect rest of script
    shopt -s dotglob
    for DIR in /home/*/; do
       DIRNAME=`basename "$DIR"`

       # do whatever with "$DIR" or "$DIRNAME"
       echo -n "$DIRNAME"|od -t cz
    done
)
```

Note the trailing slash and the quoted variables.

**Edit:**

With directories and file

```
mkdir /home/..abc
mkdir /home/.abc
mkdir /home/$'a\nc'
mkdir /home/'a?c'
mkdir /home/abc
mkdir /home/'foo bar'
touch /home/test
```

This gives me the output

```
0000000   .   .   a   b   c                                              >..abc<
0000005
0000000   .   a   b   c                                                  >.abc<
0000004
0000000   a  \n   c                                                      >a.c<
0000003
0000000   a   ?   c                                                      >a?c<
0000003
0000000   a   b   c                                                      >abc<
0000003
0000000   f   o   o       b   a   r                                      >foo bar<
0000007
```

where

```
ls -1 -F -b -A /home
```

gives me the output

```
..abc/
.abc/
a\nc/
a?c/
abc/
foo bar/
test
```

(`test` is a file)

Comment: This will fail on dirnames with blanks in the name.

Comment: @user: No it won't, i explicitly tested for that, and that's why i quoted the variables. Bash is intelligent about its globbing.

Comment: The new version fails, if there is a directory "a?c" and a directory "abc".

Comment: I'm sorry, I tried your first example with cut-and-paste, and it failed, but in the history of your edit, I only find the version with "$DIR", so I'm astonished what went wrong. But it is still not safe for linefeeds in filenames, and Mahaakal asked for a safe solution.

Comment: @user: It is quite safe. The directory name with the newline will be contained in both `"$DIR"` and `"$DIRNAME"`. I just tested it. It's only the echo at the end of my example that it will output on two lines, which is what a newline is supposed to do. It will still be a single parameter to any command, as long as it is quoted when used.

Comment: I've edited my answer again to further prove my point, using `od` to print out each character.

Comment: Ah. I tested it with `echo $DIRNAME` instead of `echo "$DIRNAME"`. My fault, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

[No](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). If you're really paranoid, you can use the [Safe Find](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/master/examples/safe-find.sh) (R)(C)(TM)(FLOSS).

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' -u 9
do
    some_command "${REPLY}"
done 9< <( find "/home" -print0 )
```

Comment: What is "${file_path}"? shouldn't it be initialized? Your script doesn't work for me.

Answer (score -1):

```
find -type d -execdir COMMAND {} +
```

is the way to do it. Find will organize, that names which contain blanks and linefeeds and so on are properly passed to COMMAND. + will allow for multiple names to be passed - you may use `... {} ";"` instead. Instead of -execdir you may use -okdir, which asks for confirmation (very safe! :) ).

Comment: Is this alright  **for FOLDERNAME in `find /home/ -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's/\/home\///'`; do**

Comment: What are you trying to reach? `find` knows already where a foldername starts, and where it ends. If you put the result through sed, you end with a string, which might fail. In many cases you can do, whatever you liked to do in the for-loop, with the -execdir option, like `... -execdir basename {} +`. If you just want to print the name, `find -type d -printf "%f\n"` might be interesting. The for-loop will do string splitting, so `for FOLDERNAME in $(find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type d | sed 's/\/home\///'); do echo $FOLDERNAME; done` ends in a mess, if your names contains blanks and linefeeds.

Comment: i tried us answer but it also print home also as folder 2) i tried sed by having spaces , \n in dirs and it worked . i want to see the problem case

Comment: To avoid that, use -mindepth too: `find /home/ -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\n"`

Comment: wow thanks that worked , looks like there must be a complete book on find command . Any full fledge tutorial on that??

Comment: The find-manual is pretty verbose, but most parts are quiete simple, if you take them step by step. But you can build very complex commands by combining the parts in a very free manner.